# changing footer color in a asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, footer

I'm using ASP. NET to build a web site by using a master page: 
I have a header and a footer on every page in my web site. 
I would like to know is it possible to change the background color of the footer only on 1 special page that I have?    hope I explained myself ok.

Comment: Create separate user control and apply different color via CSS to that by checking the page title using the master page.

Answer (score 0):

If your footer is a div (asp:Panel) in your master page, you may access the div (Panel) in your master page.

```
ContentPlaceHolder footerPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder) Master.FindControl("FooterPlaceHolder");
Panel footer;
if(footerPlaceHolder != null)
{
    footer = (Panel) footerPlaceHolder.FindControl("footerDivInMasterPage");
    if(footer != null)
    {
        footer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
    }
}
```